# I have created a custom field that displays fine in a list edit form, but I cannot get it to render is an application page

Tags: custom, rendering-template

The field inherits from a multi part field (its for our billing code).  If I place on the page:

```
<td class="form-control">
  <srm:BillingCodeFieldControl ID="billingCode" runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"></srm:BillingCodeFieldControl>
</td>
```

It does not render at all.

I have debugged it and the custom Field Control method CreateChildControls is getting called, so I am confused.

It renders just fine if I go into the list view and select "Edit Item".
I'm thinking that since I have no associated List item until I submit the form, and hence no associated Field that may be the issue...

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it render if you View the list item (not the edit view)

Comment: If I view the list item, it shows just the standard Display template that a multipart item shows, basically like a text field.  If I then click edit item, the custom control template I defines shows up.

Comment: I also face the same situation. In display form and view form you have to use JSLink. The custom controls doesn't render. Override the JSLink in where you inherit SPFieldText If you are able to find any other solutions please let me know.